# Tensorflow Lite quantization on Raspberry Pi 0 in image classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am developing an image classification model/program for Raspberry Pi 0 W. I was wondering if it is possible to make a code upgrade that will accelerate image processing.

General information:

- the main model was trained on EfficientNetB5
- image dimensions are 240x320 in grayscale
- on Raspberry, it should be an image classification, no possibility of 'live streaming' and object detection
- I acknowledge that Raspberry Pi 0 W is not the best match for TF, but anyway maybe there is a way for acceleration
- at the moment one image is being predicted in 60 seconds, which is too much

My thoughts about this are that maybe I should train the model with lower dimensions and maybe the `learning_rate` of the main model can affect rpi's speed?

Below I am attaching two scripts.

**Tensorflow save_model transformation into tf_lite quantized model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('../models/effnet_v22.h5')

TFLITE_QUANT_MODEL = "../tflite_models/effnet_v22_quant.tflite"

run_model = tf.function(lambda x : model(x))

# Save the concrete function.
concrete_func = run_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype)
)

# Convert the model to quantized version with post-training quantization
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
open(TFLITE_QUANT_MODEL, "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)

print("TFLite Quantized Model Is Created")
```

**One image processing on Raspberry Pi 0**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as img
import cv2

# uploading tflite model
tflite_interpreter =tf.lite.Interpreter(
    model_path='../../tflite_models/effnet_v22_quant.tflite')

# taking pre-trained model parameters 
input_details = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()

img_width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
img_height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]

# uploading and processing the image to be predicted
testimg=img.imread('../img/c21.jpg')
testimg=cv2.resize(testimg, (img_width,img_height))
testimg=cv2.cvtColor(testimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
testimg=testimg[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis]
testimg=np.array(testimg, dtype=np.float32)

# resizing tflite's tensors
tflite_interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], (1, img_height, img_width, 1))
tflite_interpreter.resize_tensor_input(output_details[0]['index'], (1, 8))
tflite_interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()

tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], testimg)
tflite_interpreter.invoke()
tflite_model_predictions = tflite_interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

# TFLite prediction results

classes = np.array([101,102,104,105, 107, 110, 113, 115]) # class array creation
mat = np.vstack([classes, tflite_model_predictions]) 
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision = 10) # to get rid of scientific numbers

if np.max(mat[1,:]) > 0.50:
    theclass = int(mat[0, np.argmax(mat[1,:])])
else:
    theclass = "NO_CLASS"

print(mat)

print("The predicted class is", theclass)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using EfficientNet-B5 model which has nearly 30M parameters. Even though you get benefits from Tensorflow Lite and quantization method, it is very hard to get a latency of inference below 30ms assuming you are using high-performance CPU like in Pixel 4. Considering you are using very limited powered embedded system, it is normal to get 60 seconds for one inferencing.

There exists one well-explained webpage about latency on EfficientNet-lite models. Here, you can visit, https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/03/higher-accuracy-on-vision-models-with-efficientnet-lite.html